# package android.support.v4.content does not exist flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

I got multiple errors here. Please let me know what am I doing wrong.
Following errors are generated:

```
  C:\Users\Lenovo\flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-2.2.11\android\src\main\java\io\github\ponnamkarthik\toast\fluttertoast\FluttertoastPlugin.java:14: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
                                     ^
    C:\Users\Lenovo\flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\fluttertoast-2.2.11\android\src\main\java\io\github\ponnamkarthik\toast\fluttertoast\FluttertoastPlugin.java:107: error: cannot find symbol
              Drawable shapeDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.toast_bg);
                                       ^
      symbol:   variable ContextCompat
      location: class FluttertoastPlugin
    2 errors
```

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>           * What went wrong:
>           Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> >             * Try:
> >             Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> >             * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> >             BUILD FAILED in 6s
>
> ```
>     The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
>     [!] Flutter tried to create the file `android\settings_aar.gradle`, but failed.
>     To manually update `settings.gradle`, follow these steps:
>         1. Copy `settings.gradle` as `settings_aar.gradle`
>         2. Remove the following code from `settings_aar.gradle`:
>                 def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()
>                 def plugins = new Properties()
>                 def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
>                 if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
>                     pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
>                 }
>                 plugins.each { name, path ->
>                     def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
>                     include ":$name"
>                     project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
>                 }
>     Please create the file and run this command again.
> ```

Here's my app level build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.santosenoque.chatapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"


}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')


}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: hello you got that's solution or not ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have something to do with either the project or the plugin not using Android X. To check if the Flutter project uses Android X, follow this [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/androidx-migration#how-do-i-know-if-my-project-is-using-androidx) from the docs. If the Flutter project has yet to use Android X, follow this [migration guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/androidx-migration#how-do-i-migrate-my-existing-app-plugin-or-host-editable-module-project-to-androidx). On the other hand, if the plugin causes the issue, try using its latest version and see if the latest version now uses Android X.